# VPN and Local IP Address

Tags: vpn, ip

I am using a VPN service. After recently installing a program that monitors ports, I noticed that whenever I am using my VPN, my local IP address changes. I am aware that the external IP should change from my internet provider's IP to the VPN's IP. That is what is supposed to happen and normal. What I didn't expect was for my local IP to be changed. Is this normal? Or am I using a bad VPN company? Note, my local IP address (127.0.0.1) changes to one of these IPs: 5.5.146.91, 5.5.42.100, 5.5.58.136.

Comment: Please add which VPN product you are using. Usually VPN products create an additional interface with the VPN IP.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 isn't a valid local address it's your loopback address.  Furthermore your IP address changing is normal

Comment: A VPN by definition connects a pair of peers (client -> Network; Network -> Network) at OSI layer 2, so its like they are on the same lan. you need a valid IP address for whatever lan you are connected to, so your IP must change to one that fits the remote network. if you connect from a 192.168.x.y lan to a 10.x.y.z lan, then your VPN adapter must get a 10.x.y.z in order for you to talk to the computers on the remote lan.

Comment: I am using Private Tunnel, mtak. Basically, in the ports monitor, it would show the "local address" when not logged into the VPN as 127.0.0.1. When logged in, it would instead show one of the three I've mentioned, which seemed rather strange to me and outside of what I usually see for local address. I also see, at times, when not logged into the VPN, 10.0.1.XX, with whatever number goes in place of the X, which I also know is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Run Command Prompt, type `ipconfig` and look at the output - you will see list of network adapters and their IP addresses - all of these addresses are your "local IPs". 
When you install VPN software, usually it creates new virtual network adapter, and assign new IP from some range (5.5.x.x in your case) every time when you connect.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the game. The VPN server often provides local IP addresses for its clients and sometimes let them connect each other just like in a local network. Even the DNS servers are also changed by most VPNs to bypass ISP's ban on some websites/services by means of DNS.

Answer (score -1):

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/vpn.htm

Read all of that. Internal address changing is part of the process. There is probably another network adapter.

Comment: Link-only answers are considered a no-no, please include pertinent information directly in your answers and cite the site as a source.